# Maven and Eclipse Lift Project Errors

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, lift, m2eclipse

I made a new project through the m2eclipse wizard and selected the blank liftweb archetype. The project was created and I added the scala nature to the project (I don't have the maven-scala plugin installed for the time being).

I am able to run the project using the goal `jetty:run`. However, I still have the following errors showing up in eclipse (cleaning the project didn't do anything):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error while loading Helpers, Scala signature Helpers has wrong version  expected: 5.0  found: 4.1 in C:\Users\Ken\.m2\repository\net\liftweb\lift-webkit\0.8\lift-webkit-0.8.jar(net/liftweb/util/Helpers.class)    first       Unknown Scala Problem
error while loading LiftRules, Scala signature LiftRules has wrong version  expected: 5.0  found: 4.1 in C:\Users\Ken\.m2\repository\net\liftweb\lift-webkit\0.8\lift-webkit-0.8.jar(net/liftweb/http/LiftRules.class)  first       Unknown Scala Problem
error while loading Loc, Scala signature Loc has wrong version  expected: 5.0  found: 4.1 in C:\Users\Ken\.m2\repository\net\liftweb\lift-webkit\0.8\lift-webkit-0.8.jar(net/liftweb/sitemap/Loc.class) first       Unknown Scala Problem
error while loading MainGenericRunner, Scala signature MainGenericRunner has wrong version  expected: 5.0  found: 4.1 in C:\Users\Ken\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.7.1\scala-compiler-2.7.1.jar(scala/tools/nsc/MainGenericRunner.class)  first       Unknown Scala Problem
error while loading Menu, Scala signature Menu has wrong version  expected: 5.0  found: 4.1 in C:\Users\Ken\.m2\repository\net\liftweb\lift-webkit\0.8\lift-webkit-0.8.jar(net/liftweb/sitemap/Menu.class)  first       Unknown Scala Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (execution: default, phase: compile) pom.xml /first  line 76 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:testCompile (execution: default, phase: test-compile)    pom.xml /first  line 76 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Here is a screenshot of the errors (may be easier to read, click the image for full size):

[image: Errors]

**Does anybody know what is happening here? Any suggestions?**

Additional information:

The following warnings come up when I run the project:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.kpthunder.lift:first:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin is missing. @ line 87, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for net.sf.alchim:yuicompressor-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 95, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin is missing. @ line 72, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin is missing. @ line 109, column 15
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin is missing. @ line 133, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to lift, but used the explanations [here](http://mykhalchuk.com/article/37/view?locale=en_EN), and were able to make it to work.